# Would authorisation codes in Star Trek be secure in real life?

Tags: authentication, one-time-password

I'm watching Deep Space 9 and I've noticed that they use spoken authorization codes when commanding other ships, computers, ... In the show it looks like "Authorization Some-Name 5 7 3 5 blue", then the other person types it into the computer (and looks up in fear, says "I didn't know" and files away).

Using a single code is obviously not good enough, because everyone around can overhear it, so I was thinking that maybe everyone can have a pre-generated list of these passwords both memorized and stored in a central computer and when verifying the last used code would be invalidated.

Would such a system be feasible in real life? How strong would it be?

I'm thinking about implementing a scheme like this for my home server when accessing it from the internet (mostly for the hack value, though), so I'm also interested in implementation details -- for example how to store this kind of passwords on the computer (probably hashes of all of them, right?).

Comment: Can you precise the difference between the system you are suggesting and classical [one-time passwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password)?

Comment: Since you already have the tag "one-time-password" I recommend to read the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password) about this because it might already answer your question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich You are right, I completely missed the "Hardcopy" section on the wikipedia page :-)

Comment: "Engineering authorization omega-four-seven."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not secure.

Other people can overhear the user speak the password. This compromises them easily. Also, the passwords are usually far too trivial ([with exceptions](https://youtu.be/rAUVUUhf7U0?t=22)).

A list of one-time passwords isn't a solution either. This system is actually used in the real-world. It's called a [TAN list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_authentication_number). But users are not expected to memorize them. People have physical printouts of randomly generated lists stored in a secure location which they look up if needed. When you expect users to write their own TAN lists and memorize them, you end up with far too trivial passcodes (Authorization Picard-Alpha-1... Picard-Alpha-2... Picard-Alpha-3... ah, this one works).

The starfleet computers likely also combine the passwords with biometric voice recognition, so the correct password spoken by the wrong voice won't be accepted (might want to ask on [scifi stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) for confirmation or counter-examples. I only know enough about Star Trek to not get my nerd card revoked). But as most biometric technology, this can be easily circumvented. In this case through equally advanced voice synthesis software.

It's far more likely that Starfleet authorization codes are not so much an authentication mechanism and more of a usability feature. Even the most advanced voice recognition software might get false-positives from time to time, so the most critical actions require a passcode to prevent accidental execution. It also forces the user to think twice before giving a command they might regret later. "Computer: Activate self-destruct sequence!" is said quite easily, but when the user also needs to recall their authorization code, they get some more time to consider if they *really* want to do it. Kind of the starfleet equivalent to `sudo`.

Comment: The indexed TAN list is almost exactly what I meant. Memorizing it is just for convenience (or robustness, or whatever). How long should these passwords be to be secure? They probably require about the same entropy as regular passwords, right?

Comment: @cube That depends on your attack scenario and security level. When you only consider online brute-forcing and have auto-banning after too many wrong attempts, they don't need to be that long. When you consider a server break-in scenario, then you can assume that they get cracked in no time. However, revoking a TAN list and issuing a new one is a standard process and password reuse is not a problem either.

Answer (score 2):

You could setup the Google Authenticator and use the Google app to allow access. This comes the closest to your OTP idea without building anything yourself. If you want something more fancy, you should look at tiny RSA tokens, the kind used for SecureID.

Comment: The image of Worf loading up google authenticator or authy is just too funny.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen the movie(s?) you are talking about, but -- especially in a Sci-Fi context -- there could be more going on in the background to authenticate individuals than you realise.

**Implicit authentication** has been proposed in the past decade or so as a method to overcome some usability limits of authentication systems and provide additional authentication factors at no user cost. It can include voice, pronunciation and intonation. But you could also imagine the presence of HD CCTV with facial recognition, weight and motion sensors that check if the actor's body is consistent with past interactions (height, way of walking, usual body language), etc. Other methods can include RFID-like tokens worn by individuals, the proximity and location of which authenticates their bodies.

Ultimately, a short code over an audio channel (possibly with adversarial observers) is not secure at all, but the setting in which it occurs provides for additional factors that can make attacks somewhat easier to spot.

As these methods all come with some degree of failure, one will need a stronger explicit multi-factor authentication scheme for when the legitimate user cannot be recognised. Of course, taking some swipe-card out of your pocket, doing an iris scan and typing out a 14 character password is not very sexy on TV (and not very quick in real life), so that won't be shown on screen five times per episode of your series / movie.

Comment: Why do adversarial observers matter for one time passwords? This way the observer will get a password that is already being invalidated, so no harm done, right?

Comment: @cube ehm, sorry, neither the title nor the question mentioned OTPs so I had no idea it was about that. Either way, observing genuine inputs is useful for people who want to attack security systems based on probabilistic models. Look up adversarial machine learning if interested. In the case of implicit authentication, all that literature would apply, so adversarial observation of OTPs would still be useful to model and simulate the implicit auth factors.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what the authentication is for.

In some places law enforcement officers have id codes so that when they call an emergency line (like 911) they don't have to go through the whole situation assessment script.

Worst case scenario, someone overhears the code and can use it to report an emergency or make a prank.

It can also work in a situation where there actually is no authentication. When I call our ISP at work I say "I'm from IT at customer NNN" and they patch me through to their "advanced" tech support. Depending on the situation they may later take steps to verify my claim, but not to patch me through.

> In the show it looks like "Authorization Some-Name 5 7 3 5 blue", then
>   the other person types it into the computer (and looks up in fear,
>   says "I didn't know" and files away).

This sounds exactly right. "A" claims to be Some-Name, but since there's a lot of people in this universe they don't do name lookups, hence the number.

"B" queries the number in the database and a profile comes up. There's a picture that matches the person in front of him, the name also matches, and it also says Some-Name outranks him by quite a margin. Hence the fear.

Of course this scheme wouldn't work for the missile launch sequence, but it's good enough in many situations.